# JBoss Web Services Behind IIS Through HTTPs

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws

This is a tangled web that's woven, I suppose, but it really shouldn't be all that hard.  Let me see if I can paint the picture:

I have written a web service, starting with a WSDL, which is to run in JBoss.  This is all fine and dandy when I run it on my local machine and point my Netbeans "client generator" (probably just using "wsimport" or whatever behind the scenes) at it to generate a client it works as expected.  All of this is working by hitting port 8080 directly and the `<soap:address>` element looks like so:

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/MyoutfitWebService/funService"/>
```

Now, when this puppy gets deployed, it will be getting requests from IIS forwarded through AJP to, I think, port 8009.  IIS handles our client certificate validation and then is supposed to just forward the request to my web service.  I can't figure out what to use in my WSDL's `<soap:address>` element so that I can give the WSDL URL to someone to generate their own client.  If I use:

```
<soap:address location="https://real.server.com/MyoutfitWebService/funService"/>
```

when I deploy it and point to the WSDL, the `<soap:address>` element is wrecked and looks something like:

```
<soap:address location="https://127.0.0.1:8443/MyoutfitWebService/funService"/>
```

Can someone tell me if I need to modify something in jbossws.sar jboss-beans.xml or what?
I'm using JBoss Web Services Native 3.0.4.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Duh.  Turns out that this is addressed reasonably well at this FAQ: http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/JBossWS-FAQ

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to handle this in IIS but i'll write some notes about Apache

I had the same problem and workarounded it using mod_ext module in apache

Your configuration will look like this

```
 ExtFilterDefine fixservice mode=output cmd="/bin/sed s/127.0.0.1:8443/real.server.com:443/g"

 <Location "/MyoutfitWebService/services/funService">
      ProxyPass ajp://local.server.com:8009/MyoutfitWebService/funService   
      SetOutputFilter fixservice
 </Location>
 ProxyPass /MyoutfitWebService/funService ajp://local.server.com:8009/MyoutfitWebService/funService
```

So, your "correct" WSDL address will be

```
 real.server.com/MyoutfitWebService/services/funService?wsdl
```

which will have correct soap:address,

```
 real.server.com/MyoutfitWebService/funService
```

(I have removed https as I can put only one hyperlink here).

There may be a better way but unfortunately I have no time to do deep investigation. This solution just works (I found it couple of minutes ago and already tested)